# Does Union Affect randomness Vertica SQL

Tags: sql, vertica

I'm seeing very strange results from a query of a vertica database. Here is the structure of the query

```
select column_a
FROM
(......
.......
ORDER BY RANDOM()
limit 500
) proxy
UNION
(....
.....
ORDER BY RANDOM()
limit 500
)
```

Here's the weird behavior I'm getting. If i run both subqueries independently, their results are randomized. If i run both subqueries independently inside an outer select statement, the results are randomized. However, when I select the results via the query above unioning them together, the results are no longer randomized, the data is always the same. This doesn't make sense to me and I can't think of any explanation.

**Edit**: weirdly, changing union to union all restored the randomness. My queries are even getting different more realistic results. It's very strange though because when i put the two suqueries into a:

```
select * from (........
union .............
) GROUP by a HAVING count(a) > 1
```

no results are ever returned no matter how many times I run the code. So effectively their should have been no difference.

What is even STRANGER however is the following. If I switch the order of the subqueries, so that the 2nd one is within the FROM statement and the first is within the UNION statement, now the 2nd query gets randomized results and the first does not. My question is further evolving into: does union remove inner order by statements? Even when doing so actually affects the results?

**RESOLUTION**

I have no idea why in the world this would change anything but the following fixes the problem:

select column_a

```
SELECT *
FROM
(......
.......
ORDER BY RANDOM()
limit 500
) proxy
UNION
(SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT ....
    .....
    ORDER BY RANDOM()
    limit 500
    ) proxy2
)
```

Apparently adding an outer select statement inside the union gets sql to respect the order by random() statement. If anyone has any explanation it would be greatly appreciated. Starting to lose a little faith in my results from sql.

Comment: Have you compared the `EXPLAIN` plans?

Comment: Voting to close this question. Without `EXPLAIN` plans, there's not enough information to try and form an idea of what is happening.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't feel comfortable posting the explain plans, the database is not mine and don't want to reveal any information about the columns